# Detect battery type (NiMH, 14500, alkaline) and only charge the rechargable types

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, battery-chemistry

I'm building a flashlight that uses AA size batteries. I want to automatically detect the battery type and charge it with the appropiate method, and also detect alkaline cells so it won't try to charge them.

My flashlight uses a 2-cell design, but it's in early development so I can still alter it.

Is there an IC that can do this?

Comment: Welcome! Not an answer, but my 20-year old smart NiMH charger (-deltaV) does detect and throws an error code when alkaline cells are inserted, so it’s certainly possible. Don’t know how but hopefully someone will provide an answer for you.

Comment: Please add a question which you want answered to help with what you want to achieve.

Comment: There are multi chemistry chargers  out there (BQ25730 for example). I don't know if they support alkaline batteries.